# Oracle + finding match between semicolon-separated columns

Tags: sql

I have a table with two columns A and B where the values are semi colon separated.

- A has value `'a;b;c;d;e'`
- B has value `'a;b;d;e'`

I want to check that if value in column B are all present in column A.

Please guide me.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fix your data structure.  Storing lists of things as strings is very bad practice in SQL.  The proper way to store a list is in a row in a different table, with one row per list item.

In your example, both lists are ordered alphabetically.  If you know this is always true, you can do something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.a like '%' || replace(t.b, ';', '%') || %;
```

This does not do what you want 100%, but it may be close enough for your purposes.

Comment: I thought `||` means `OR`. But seems you've used it as a combination *(something like dot `.` in PHP)*. Well what's going on here? What's the meaning of `||` in MySQL?

Comment: @Alex . . . The question refers to Oracle.  In Oracle (and Postgres and ANSI SQL and some other databases), `||` concatenates strings.  In MySQL, it can be either logic OR or string concatenation, depending on the ANSI SQL mode.

Answer (score 0):

Double bars are concatenation.

```
SELECT `first_name`||`last_name` FROM users;
```

You'll get a column named:
`first_name`||`last_name`

So your query `where t.a like '%' || replace(t.b, ';', '%') || %;`

would take `'a;b;d;e'` and output `%a%b%d%e%`